# Combine glossary and Acronym and keep the correct sorting

Tags: glossaries

I combined acronyms and the glossary into one list with the following code.

Unfortunately, some entries in the glossary don't have a long form. I tried to handle this with an `\,`.

But this leads to an unsorted list. Has anyone an idea, how to solve this?

Thank you very much!

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

%\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}

\usepackage[acronym,
nomain,
nopostdot,
nonumberlist,
toc]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\setacronymstyle{long-short-desc}
\renewcommand*{\acronymentry}[1]{\acronymfont{\glsentryshort{#1}} \textnormal{--\glsentrylong{#1}--}} % Print it the way I want

\newacronym[description={some description}]{ABC}{ABC}{ABC-long}
\newacronym[description={some description}]{BCD}{BCD}{\,}
\newacronym[description={some description}]{Test}{Test}{Test-long}

\begin{document}

\glsaddall % auch wenn nicht Referenziert alle Anzeigen
\printglossaries

\chapter{Abstract}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image: image of glossary]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default sort for the `long-short-desc` is the `long` value. Since this has been set to `\,`, `makeindex` puts it in the "Symbols" group at the start. You can simply override it using the `sort` key like this:

```
\newacronym[description={some description},sort={BCD}]{BCD}{BCD}{\,}
```

This instructs `makeindex` to sort it according to `BCD`.

Complete MWE (thank you for providing one!):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[acronym,
nomain,
nopostdot,
nonumberlist,
toc]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\setacronymstyle{long-short-desc}
\renewcommand*{\acronymentry}[1]{\acronymfont{\glsentryshort{#1}} \textnormal{--\glsentrylong{#1}--}} % Print it the way I want

\newacronym[description={some description}]{ABC}{ABC}{ABC-long}
\newacronym[description={some description},sort={BCD}]{BCD}{BCD}{\,}
\newacronym[description={some description}]{Test}{Test}{Test-long}

\begin{document}

\glsaddall
\printglossaries

\chapter{Abstract}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image: image of glossary]